# systemd service that starts before user interaction, possible?

Tags: linux, service, systemd

It is possible to make a systemd service that will start before console output "login as, password" etc?

Target is to prevent user input before service starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Blabla
After=docker.service
Before=getty@tty1.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/something
ConditionPathExists=/etc/something2

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/test
StandardOutput=tty
StandardError=tty

[Install]
WantedBy=getty.target
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe so.
A systemd service generally looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=my service unit
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
Group=root
Environment=enter env here
ExecStart=enter command
ExecStartPost=enter command
ExecStop=enter command
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

All you have to do is to set it to run after and before something that runs before the login options come up. You do this by changing the `After` and `WantedBy`